# I don't understand the calculus problem from my note?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I don't understand the highlight part in my note from class. Why we have to multiply this? Can someone explain it for me? Why $n-1$ power? Thanks!

Comment: That is proportional to the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume of the boundary of the ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $d\omega$ as the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume of an infinitely small part of the $(n-1)$-sphere $S^{n-1}\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ of unit radius.  Multiply every point on that sphere by $\rho$ and you've got the sphere of radius $\rho$, and the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume of the corresonding infinitely small part of that sphere is $\rho^{n-1}$ time as big, so it's $\rho^{n-1}\,d\omega$.

In the $2$-dimensional case, with polar coordinates, people write $r\,dr\,d\theta$, but in a sense it's really $dr\,(r\,d\theta)$ (but that doesn't mean you necessarily want to compute the integral that way).